# error in submitting iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode5, xcode-organizer

I tried many times to upload my application but after about 50% succeed,
Then this message show to me

[image]

Note: application size about 600 MB
What does it mean ?
And how can I fix it ?

Comment: try upload with "application loader".

Comment: how can i upload it via application loader.
I made the archive and the application loader did not accept the archive.

Comment: why not  accept can you give reason of that ?

Comment: I don't know.
I opened the application loader the I clicked to "deliver your app" after that,I chooses the application,then I clicked choose after that files dialog box show to me,after that I determine the archive file .xcarchive
then It is non clickable

Comment: you have to submit the xcode>>product>>"bulid" of zip file of that not archieve means ipa ok ...

Comment: Where is the zip file location path ?